# I see a gap between my img and my right box

Tags: ios, css

I'm having some difficulty getting my website to display properly when viewed on the iPhone and iPad. The website displays properly when viewed on every desktop browser I've tried (safari, chrome, firefox), however, on the iPhone/iPad there is a tiny gap/space between the IMG and right box.
It works fine in Firefox. What is the problem?
Here's an inline link to [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZSF9Y/).

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/155x155/000/fff"/>
    <div id="subject">
        <div id="subject_wrapper">
            <span>Im span</span>
            <span>im spanfdnf</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>



#wrapper {
    border-top: 8px solid #457b91;
    max-width: 488px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper img {
    width: 32%;
    float: left;
}

#subject {
    background-color: green;
    float: right;
    width: 68%;
    padding-bottom: 32%;
    position: relative;
}

#subject_wrapper {
    padding-top: 12%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

#subject span {
    font-family: Thonburi;
    font-size: 34px;
    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    padding: 0 20%;
}

#subject span:nth-child(2) {
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Did u test it in safari on desktop? u will see the gap/ space

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an iPd or iPhone to hand to check this, but try commenting out the space between your elements, thus:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <img src="http://dummyimage.com/155x155/000/fff"/><!--
    --><div id="subject">
        <div id="subject_wrapper">
            <span>Im span</span>
            <span>im spanfdnf</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It's a pretty ridiculous fix, but it work for inline block elements, like menus made up of LIs.

Comment: what do u mean? i dont understand

Comment: Well, unless I've misunderstood you, there's a small gap between your elements that you didn't expect?

Often this kind of unexpected gap is a result of the actual white space in the code, which inserts a single space character as if the elements were part of a text flow. Commenting out the gap between elements can fix this, as can setting the space between to a font size of 0 or just butting each element against each other.

Here's a pen to explain: http://cdpn.io/bFLus

I may have misunderstood, in which case I'm sorry, I didn't have chance to look at the Fiddle on an IOS device